# Overloading based on bool template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I have a template class with a single bool template parameter. I want to be able to implicitly convert from instantiations with the parameter equal to `true`, to those where it is equal to `false`.

I tried doing this (for the copy constructor), but the problem is that when I have `Foo<true>`, there are now two versions of the same constructor (with the same signature).

```
template <bool B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Foo& other);
    Foo(const Foo<true>& other);
};
```

Not sure how to implement this? I also intend to have similar code for a move constructor and assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), to make `Foo(const Foo<true>& other)` only valid with `Foo<false>`.

```
template <bool B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Foo& other);
    template <bool b = B, std::enable_if_t<!b>* = nullptr> // when b is false
    Foo(const Foo<true>& other);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20, you'll be able to write something like this:

```
template<bool B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Foo& other) 
        : Foo(other, Tag{}) { }

    Foo(const Foo<true>& other) 
    requires(!B)               
        : Foo(other, Tag{}) { }

private:
    struct Tag {};

    template<bool B1>
    Foo(const Foo<B1>& other, Tag) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Here the [`requires`-clause](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses) is used instead of SFINAE (see songyuanyao's answer). The private constructor with `Tag` parameter can be used to avoid code duplication. You might also need to make `Foo<true>` a friend of `Foo<false>`.

Comment: This isn't a copy constructor (`Foo<true>(t)` calls an implicity generated one, and `Foo<false>(f)` would also call an implicitly generated one. Only `Foo<false>(t)` calls this constructor)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using `enable_if` if you need to distinguish between `Foo<false>` and `Foo<true>`. The following should work:

```
template <bool B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Foo<true>& other);
    Foo(const Foo<false>& other);
    // ...
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_9NNhR

---

Following the comment, to forbid conversion from false to true the following code would to the work:

```
template <bool B>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<bool Other>
    Foo(const Foo<Other>& other) {}
    Foo() {}
};

template <>
template <>
Foo<true>::Foo(const Foo<false>&) = delete;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/NjghXK

---

If we want to replace the copy ctor and avoid conversion from false to true:

```
template <bool B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Foo<true>& other) {
        std::cout << true << " set to " << B << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(const Foo<false>& other) {
        std::cout << false << " set to " << B << std::endl;
    }
    Foo() {}
};

template <>
Foo<true>::Foo(const Foo<false>&) = delete;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zt8VMb

Comment: I don't want the conversion from false to true though.

Comment: @emil.indzhev added another version that forbids conversion from false to true

Comment: In the second version you still need to define a copy constructor `Foo(const Foo& other)`. If you don't define it, the compiler will generate one for you implicitly, and it will be preferred to the templated one.

Comment: @Evg, added another version. The idea is that eventually things can be achieved **in this case** based on _specialization_, no need for `enable_if` or `requires`